# Achartengine- Bar chart -Size of Chart on Small Screens

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using horizontal and vertical bar charts. It is working great with large screens, but working messy with small screens.
How can I scale the charts for different sizes of screens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using multiple series and each series has only one item. This is the perfect case for using `renderer.setBarWidth(width)` and the `width` to be computed based on the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Use scale option for increase and decrease the size of a chart..

renderer.setScale((float) 1);